# SWIFT: navigationviewcontroller does not transition the app to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, tvos

```
   @IBAction func activateDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    
    /*Testing transitioning to another view controller just by a button click**/
    print("Activate Did Touch was triggered")
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc: LoginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}}
```

When I click on that the button connected to that function, nothing happens.
This does get printed though:

```
print("Activate Did Touch was triggered")
```

I have verified the ViewController identifier. And so everything theoretically should work.

[image]

Comment: When you use something like `.navigationController?.` you're saying "if I have a navigation controller, use it; otherwise carry on and don't even tell me there's a problem".  It doesn't take much more effort to actually *test* whether your setup is the way you want it and print a message if it isn't.

Comment: I only started learning Swift recently. So it's not that obvious to me.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the second method mentioned [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-navigate-from-one-view-controller-to-another-in-ios) and it solved my problem:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
//self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```